# Error: No value for argument 'coro' in method call and variable error is not defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot using the discord.py library. The following function is supposed to kick the user. When the user doesn't pass the name of the user it's supposed to kick, The bot should send the message: "Please specify the user you want to kick". Except when I type in the following code

```
#kick command
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} has been kicked for: "{reason}".')

#this is where the error should be written
@bot.event()
async def on_command_error(ctx, errors):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please specify the user you want to kick")
```

I get 2 errors: The first one is about the `@bot` in the `@bot.event()` line of code. The error is "No value for argument 'coro' in method call"
The other one is about the "error" in the `if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):` Line of code. The error is: `Undefined variable 'error'`. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1- The `@bot.event` should be without `()`

2- It is `commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument` You were missing the `errors`

3- `async def on_command_error(ctx, error):` it is `error` not `errors`

```py
#kick command
@bot.command()
@has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    await ctx.send(f'User {member.mention} has been kicked for: "{reason}".')

#this is where the error should be written
@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("Please specify the user you want to kick")
```

Note: The error message is general for all commands.

Comment: `2`: this isn't true. `commands.MRA` (without `.errors.` inbetween) is an alias because it's shorter, it works as well. And `3` is not entirely right either - the name of a variable in a function header doesn't matter at all, the real issue is that he's using it with the wrong name later on.

Comment: Thanks for the help sir. You helped me a lot!